# json format error when creating object with arrays as values

Tags: arrays, json

I want to create a json object (to be later used as a `mongodb` document, but that's of no particular importance for the moment).

I want the document to have in its top level the week identifier as key. Its value will be an array.

So far so good.

I want then each of this array's key-value pairs to have:

- the name of the day as key
- an array as element with the various food types offered as key value pairs.

Here is my sample:

```
{
   "Week_18_25_12":[
      "Monday": [
         {
            "vegan":"food1"
         },
         {
            "regular":"food1"
         },
         {
            "vegeterian":"food3"
         },
         {
            "veggie":"food4"
         },
         {
            "salad":"mysalad"
         }
      ],
      "Tuesday": [
         {
            "vegan":"food1"
         },
         {
            "regular":"food1"
         },
         {
            "vegeterian":"food3"
         },
         {
            "veggie":"food4"
         },
         {
            "salad":"mysalad"
         }
      ]
      ]
}
```

I cannot understand why I get a format error right on the semicolon following the name of the day. (when I replace it with a comma, it is OK)

Isn't this supposed to be a key-value pair with the day name as key and the array with food types as value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format should be like

```
{
    "Week_18_25_12":{
       // and the other key-pairs inside
    }
}
```

instead of **"Week_18_25_12":[ ]**